# WF4 Multithreading - Within & Without Visual Studio 2010

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

i have a producer-consumer multi-threaded project pulling the 1 million rows and looping through each one. every iteration is calling the invoke method of workflow-invoker. since it is a kind of small call and also want to be a synchronous call, when i run it in the visual studio 2010, it does not use cpu peak (which i expect to be 80/90%) however, as soon as i run it without visual studio i.e. running the exe file off of the console, it works fine and hits the peak. 
just for the additional information, WorkflowInvoker and CustomWorkflow are instantiated for each of the thread so that they all can have a copy of the shared resource. when each iteration occurs, it resets the input-values and then invoke the workflow.

```
while (true)
{
  row = _buffer.Receive();
  input["arg1"] = arg1;
  input["arg2"] = arg2;
  output = resource.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(input);
}
```

my question is why execution does not hit the peak when running it in the visual studio as oppose to running it from the console directly using .exe file.

thanks,
Moiz

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'run it in Visual Studio', do you mean under the debugger (F5), or just launched with VS (CTRL-F5)?

If you're running under the debugger then the performance is different, because various events (including thread starts/stops and debug trace output) cause debugging events, which the debugger has to handle.

If you don't actually want to use the debugger, then CTRL-F5 will tend to give much faster startup and slightly faster execution.

Comment: yes, i meant hitting the F5 (with debugger). but the point i want to make is when i comment out the WorkflowInvoker.Invoke statement and run it under the debugger, i get the performance, as soon as i run it with the invoke statement, the processor stays at 10/15%. i also noticed that not just performance is affected but it also writes the "(Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Workflow'" statement in the "output" window for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that running it under the debugger increases overhead that much that any blocking does not matter that much.